# How to set up FilePond js image preview

Tags: javascript, python, django, filepond

I am trying to use FilePond to allow users to upload drag and drop images. I've set up the FilePond drag and drop and I'm trying to implement the image preview feature. I've attached the css and js and included it in my html. The image preview still isn't working.

```
{% extends 'main/dashboardbase.html'%}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-tofit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/add.css'%}">
<link rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/filepond.css'%}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css'%}">
 </head>
 <body>
  <button type="submit" id="add">Save</button>
  <a href="{% url 'main:products'%}">
    <button id="cancel" >Cancel</button>
  </a>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6" id="inner">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inputform" name="form1">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <input type="text" name="product_title" id="product_title" placeholder="Give your product a name">
        <h4>Price</h4>
        <input type="text" name="product_price" id="product_price" placeholder="0.00">
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <input type="text" name="product_description" id="product_description" placeholder="Write a description about your product">
        <input type="file" name="product_images">
    </form>

  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main/add.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'main/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'main/filepond.js'%}"></script>
    <script>
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
        const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);

        FilePond.setOptions({
          server: '#'
        });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>

{% endblock%}
```

Comment: Answer is in this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/54666165/1774081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make certain that 'filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css' is loaded. That was my issue.

Comment: Make sure the plugin has been registered using the `registerPlugin` method. I don't see the call in the code so I guess it's not registered.